# microcode for windows 2016 build 1607

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I would like to know is there any microcode patch available for windows 2016 build 1607 . i have referred this link  https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4091664/kb4091664-intel-microcode-updates and searched in Microsoft update catalog https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4091664. . i don't see any patches for windows 2016 build 1607, only available for windows 10 build 1607 .

It would be greatly appreciated if you could help on this .

Answer (score 2):

The microcode update is a firmware update. You will need to check the hardware vendor to see if there are any updates.e.g. HP has released BIOS/Firmware updates for its G9/G10 servers.

Seems to remove dependency from the motherboard manufacturers (https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/03/microsoft-will-soon-start-shipping-the-intel-spectre-microcode-fixes/), Microsoft will too install the microcode updates. As far as I know, Windows 10 and 2016 codebase are the same. So you can go ahead and download the KB for Windows 10 1607 and install it on 2016.

Also, after installing the microcode updates, you will have to enable some registry keys to enable mitigations for Spectre. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4072698/windows-server-guidance-to-protect-against-the-speculative-execution

EDIT 1: The patches are only for specific Intel processors. If you have a different processor, you will have to download the Intel microcode update for your processor (Linux one) and then use [VMware CPU Microcode Update Driver](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/vmware-cpu-microcode-update-driver#instructions) to install the microcode.